# How to merge columns with different names using "merge, by=Column.name" function?

Tags: r, merge, rstudio

# Data1

```
SampleID <- c("A-01","B-01","C-01")
Value <- c(1,2,3)
data1 <- data.frame(SampleID, Value)
```

# Data2

```
SampleID <- c("A","B","C")
Value1 <- c(3,4,5)
data2 <- data.frame(SampleID,Value1)
```

# Output : What I want is the following using:
    `merge(data1, data2, by=c("SampleID"), all = TRUE)`

```
SampleID  Value  Value1
A-01        1       3
B-01        2       4
C-01        3       5
```

Comment: Use arguments `by.x` and `by.y`.

Comment: So you want to merge the row `A-01` with the row `A`, etc? If so, you will have to first make those values equal, creating a new column with `gsub`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first split SampleID from data1 and then concatenate it.

```
SampleID <- c("A-01","B-01","C-01")
Sample <- substr(SampleID,1,1)
Num <- substr(SampleID,3,5)
Value <- c(1,2,3)
data1 <- data.frame(Sample ,Num, Value )

SampleID <- c("A","B","C")
Value1 <- c(3,4,5)
data2 <- data.frame(SampleID, Value1)

merged <- merge(data1, data2, by.x = "Sample", by.y = "SampleID", all = T )
merged$SampleID <- paste(merged$Sample,merged$Num, sep = "-")
merged <- merged[,c(5,3,4)]

  SampleID Value Value1
1     A-01     1      3
2     B-01     2      4
3     C-01     3      5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `sqldf` library:

```
library(sqldf); 
sqldf("SELECT data1.SampledId, data1.Vlaue, data2.Value2 FROM data1 JOIN data2 on data1.SampleID like data1.SampleID + '-%'")
```

Or using `data.table` likes the following:

```
library(data.table) 
dt1 <- data.table(data1)
dt2 <- data.table(data2)
dt1[dt2, on = .(grepl(CustomerId, CustomerId)), all = TRUE]
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following does what you need.

```
data1$NewID <- gsub("[^[:alpha:]]", "", data1$SampleID)
result <- merge(data1, data2, by.x = "NewID", by.y = "SampleID", all = TRUE)
result <- result[-1]
result
#  SampleID Value Value1
#1     A-01     1      3
#2     B-01     2      4
#3     C-01     3      5
```

You can then remove the extra column from `data1` with

```
data1 <- data1[-3]
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to collection, here is a `dplyr` solution which reads a bit easier:

```
options(stringsAsFactors = F)
SampleID <-c("A-01","B-01","C-01")
Value <- c(1,2,3)
data1 <- data.frame(SampleID, Value)

SampleID <- c("A","B","C")
Value1 <- c(3,4,5)
data2 <- data.frame(SampleID,Value1)

data1 %>% 
  mutate(new_id = gsub("[^[:alpha:]]", "", SampleID)) %>% 
  left_join(., data2, by = c("new_id" = "SampleID")) %>% 
  select(-new_id)

  SampleID Value Value1
1     A-01     1      3
2     B-01     2      4
3     C-01     3      5
```